# Regex matching file path doesn't work

Tags: regex, brunch

I'm having a problem with a regular expression and i think that should be pretty easy for you.

I need a regex that matches the file path like this:

> Matching all files (xxx.test.less) into app/views/ and relative sub folders

I've been trying for days already but i can't find the right regex to fit my needs.

i tried:

```
app\/views\/[.test.less]
app\/views\/*.test.less
app\/views\/^.test.less
```

and many more but with no luck..

here's the regex playground with a file structure:

http://regexr.com/3c5jt

thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

This regular expression needs to be used with brunch config file (https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md) and currently none of the solutions are working.

Comment: [`app\/views\/.*?\.test\.less`](http://regexr.com/3c5k3)?

Comment: `app\/views\/[\w]*.test.less` or even better `app\/views\/[\w\.\/]*`

Comment: @Nick Looks like you've made up your own regex syntax; no wonder it doesn't work. It's an easy enough task, so if you'd read some documentation or a tutorial you'd have solved it in notime.

Comment: Unfortunately, i need it to be used with brunch config file (https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md) and none of the above answer works...

Comment: [Works](http://regexr.com/3c5kc) with your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you'll be using it with `brunch`, try:

```
/app\/views\/.*?\.test\.less$/
```

Comment: YES! Thank you very very very much! it's working now!